# TeamCity LDAP configuration problems

Tags: ldap, teamcity

I'm trying to configure LDAP authentication for teamcity but can't get it to work. I already configured some other services on this server to authenticate using LDAP and had no problems (so it's not fault of the DC).

Following describes my config file:

```
java.naming.provider.url=ldap://192.168.0.123:389/DC=server,DC=example,DC=com
java.naming.security.principal=ldap-user
java.naming.security.credentials=jE&4i.%$lpDr3#?
java.naming.security.authentication=simple
teamcity.users.login.filter=(&(sAMAccountName=$capturedLogin$)(memberOf=CN=Group1,CN=Users,DC=server,DC=example,DC=com))
teamcity.users.username=sAMAccountName
teamcity.auth.loginFilter=[^/\\\\@]+
teamcity.options.users.synchronize=false
teamcity.options.groups.synchronize=false
```

When I set authentication to 'none' it works (but I can't restrict access to a specific group). I also tried using the full user name (incl. domain; i.e. DOMAIN\ldap-user) and also tried to use full DN instead, but it didn't change anything.

In log i see that the ldap server returns error code 49, which means that the binding failed. Like mentioned before I already configured other services on this server to authenticate with the same ldap server and the same binding user and had no problems.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try setting `teamcity.groups.base` ?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately I already tried this and it did not help. This problem seems to be due to the binding. St this point it doesn't query any group information.

Answer (score -2):

This is my configuration and It working fine. The synchronization is allowed so information like email and name there are no available but enable the login with NT `Id` and Credentials

```
java.naming.provider.url=ldap://amer.xxxx.com:389/DC=amer,DC=xxxx,DC=com
java.naming.security.principal=CN=SRVAMR-xxx,OU=CMAPPS,OU=Service,OU=Accounts,DC=amer,DC=xxxx,DC=com
java.naming.security.credentials=Pf867955
teamcity.users.login.filter=(&(sAMAccountName=$capturedLogin$)(memberOf=CN=AMR-GENOME-L,OU=GMA,OU=Security,OU=Groups,DC=amer,DC=xxxx,DC=com))teamcity.users.username=sAMAccountName
```

I Hope help you